# What do I need to change in my SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

my SQL Statement isnt working yet.

Here I show you the actual statement:

```
 UPDATE [sysdba].[Z_SKM]
SET Branche_Firma_val = (select  Text from ZDEFPROPERTY
                        join ZSYSPROPERTY
                        on ZDEFPROPERTY.ZDEFPROPERTYID=ZSYSPROPERTY.ZDEFPROPERTYID
                        where  ZSYSPROPERTY.SYSPROPERTYID =branche_firma_key and Valuetype = 'branch')

WHERE branche_firma_key is not  null
```

Explanation: 
I have a table called Z_SKM which two important columns 1. Branche_firma_val ; 2. Branche_firma_key

My goal is to fill Branche_firma_val with the Text from Zdefproperty if branche_firma_key is not null (so it is filled with a key).
In ZDEFPROPERTY is the Text column
In ZSYSPROPERTY is the ID (key) column 
that's why i Joined them. 
Now in I have in one row value + key

If I let run the statement it says to many results for = operator. I guess the result of the select returns all Texts where sysproperty=Firma_key.
My problem is that i dont know how I can tell it that i need for every row another key..

Do you know what I mean?

I hope so

Cheers Steven

edit:

Example

Z_SKM

Branche_firma_Key = 221

branche_firma_val = NULL

---

ZDEFPROPERTY JOINED WITH ZSYSPROPERTY

Text= "salesman"

syspropertyid = "221"

---

Solution should be:

branche_firma_key=221

branche_firma_val=salesman

---

Problem in every row is Brnache_firma_key a different one.
I guess I need a soluation which makes an iterativ sql statement.

Comment: The inner query probably returns more than one row, which is why the update is failing. Can you please give some sample data sets to clarify your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
UPDATE [sysdba].[Z_SKM]
    SET Branche_Firma_val = (select Text
                             from ZDEFPROPERTY join
                                  ZSYSPROPERTY
                                  on ZDEFPROPERTY.ZDEFPROPERTYID = ZSYSPROPERTY.ZDEFPROPERTYID
                             where ZSYSPROPERTY.SYSPROPERTYID = branche_firma_key and
                                   Valuetype = 'branch'
                            )
    WHERE branche_firma_key is not  null;
```

The correlated subquery is returning more than one row.  You need to choose among the rows that match.  Here is one way:

```
UPDATE [sysdba].[Z_SKM]
    SET Branche_Firma_val = (select max(Text)
                             from ZDEFPROPERTY join
                                  ZSYSPROPERTY
                                  on ZDEFPROPERTY.ZDEFPROPERTYID = ZSYSPROPERTY.ZDEFPROPERTYID
                             where ZSYSPROPERTY.SYSPROPERTYID = branche_firma_key and
                                   Valuetype = 'branch'
                            )
    WHERE branche_firma_key is not  null;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, yes I know that it doesnt work because of multiple rows.  My problem or better my next goal is to tell the statement that I need for every row another branche_firma_key. I will add an example.